# Is there a way to modify chromes Add to Home Screen popup modal ? I want to use my own UI for modal

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, beforeinstallprompt

[image]This is the default chrome add to home screen modal which I want to modify with my own UI. i have searched for the solution but unfortunately couldn't find any thing in this concern

Comment: Nope you can't customize prompt modal as it's a browser feature

Comment: @JaromandaX actually that was about how you can customize the install work flow of PWA not the modal Dialogue for install. I was talking about UI not the flow